# Removing plot's blank space where data does not exist

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib

Please consider `df` comprised of array `s` and `index`:

```
s = array([-1.95283961, -1.88132165, -2.23891144, -2.01005397, -1.9671432 ,
       -2.16739348, -1.86701806, -1.33778516, -1.40930312, -1.42360671,
       -1.43791031, -1.43791031, -0.32223015, -0.45096248, -0.7513379 ,
       -0.85146305, -0.77994509, -0.43665889, -0.36514093, -1.06601692])


index = DatetimeIndex(['2019-10-03 15:20:00', '2019-10-03 15:25:00', '2019-10-03 15:30:00', '2019-10-03 15:35:00', '2019-10-03 15:40:00', '2019-10-03 15:45:00', '2019-10-03 15:50:00', '2019-10-03 15:55:00', '2019-10-03 16:00:00', '2019-10-03 16:05:00', '2019-10-03 16:10:00', '2019-10-03 16:15:00', '2019-10-04 09:30:00', '2019-10-04 09:35:00', '2019-10-04 09:40:00', '2019-10-04 09:45:00', '2019-10-04 09:50:00', '2019-10-04 09:55:00', '2019-10-04 10:00:00', '2019-10-04 10:05:00'], dtype='datetime64[ns]', freq=None)

df = pd.DataFrame({'s':s}, index = index)
```

***Issue***: When I plot `df`, there is blank space between the last datetime index of 2019-10-03 and the first datetime index of the next day (2019-10-04), wasting the plot area and creating a connecting line between the two data points.

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.plot(df)
xfmt = mdates.DateFormatter('%d-%m-%y %H:%M')
ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(xfmt)
```

[image]
***Question***: How can I remove such black spaces where data does not exist on some datetime indices?

Answer (score 0):

#### Update from comments:

```
s = np.array([-1.95283961, -1.88132165, -2.23891144, -2.01005397, -1.9671432 ,
       -2.16739348, -1.86701806, -1.33778516, -1.40930312, -1.42360671,
       -1.43791031, -1.43791031, -0.32223015, -0.45096248, -0.7513379 ,
       -0.85146305, -0.77994509, -0.43665889, -0.36514093, -1.06601692])


index = pd.DatetimeIndex(['2019-10-03 15:20:00', '2019-10-03 15:25:00', '2019-10-03 15:30:00', '2019-10-03 15:35:00', '2019-10-03 15:40:00', '2019-10-03 15:45:00', '2019-10-03 15:50:00', '2019-10-03 15:55:00', '2019-10-03 16:00:00', '2019-10-03 16:05:00', '2019-10-03 16:10:00', '2019-10-03 16:15:00', '2019-10-04 09:30:00', '2019-10-04 09:35:00', '2019-10-04 09:40:00', '2019-10-04 09:45:00', '2019-10-04 09:50:00', '2019-10-04 09:55:00', '2019-10-04 10:00:00', '2019-10-04 10:05:00'], dtype='datetime64[ns]', freq=None)

df = pd.DataFrame({'s':s}, index = index)

df.index = df.index.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.plot(df)
ax.set_xticklabels(df.index, rotation=90);
```

[image]

---

Try:

```
df.resample('5T').asfreq().plot()
```

[image]

---

Or

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.plot(df.resample('5T').asfreq())
xfmt = mdates.DateFormatter('%d-%m-%y %H:%M')
ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(xfmt)
```

Comment: Thanks; This removes the line but that space is still there.

Comment: Change your index to string dtype then plot.